# Wrapping to anchor tag without html injection 2.5 M

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I prevert html injection issue in my code.

I have function for wrapping all hyperlinks in string to anchor. So I have this

```
@Html.Raw(Helpers.UtilHelpers.ReplaceLinks(Model.Texts[index].Content))
```

How can I do this without this dangerous trick? Because in this way, user can do html injection.

My function ReplaceLinks replaces all hyperlinks like `http://www.google.com` to `<a href="google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`, so I want to show this line as hyperlink not as text. But I want to show like this only tags generated by my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Server.HtmlEncode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx

If the text contains html, it will be shown encoded.

**Edit: Added as helper (Extension method)**

```
public static class HtmlUrlExtension
{
    public static string RawUrl( this HtmlHelper html, string url )
    {
         return html.Raw(HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(url));
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
@Html.RawUrl(Model.Texts[index].Content)
```

Comment: Here is a final line for the html encoded text.  That should work just fine.
    @Html.Raw(HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.Texts[index].Content))

Comment: You can also put it as an extension method

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library which allows you to filter dangerous tags and scripts and safely display an HTML string entered by the user without encoding it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my function ReplaceLinks replaces all hyperlinks like http://www.google.com to <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>, so I want to show this line as hyperlink not as text. But I want to show like this only tags generated by my function.

Comment: @mesiesta, you could do the replacing you like with your function and once you are ready to output with `@Html.Raw` pass the result to AntiXss to ensure that there are not dangerous tags left.

Answer (score 0):

in your replace function add a span with custom CSS class, then style your links with that

```
<span class="myLinkClass" url-data="......">fooo</span>
```

In this way only your links will be managed by the following jQuery magic.

For accessing all your fake `<a href />` you can use a simple jQuery selector (for client side stuffs)

```
$("span.myLinkClass").each(new function() { 
   $(this).click(function () {
      location.href = $(this).attr("url-data");
   });
});
```

and of course you can style with it

```
.myLinkClass { color: yellow; }
```